# Interpreting a list traversal with condition?

Tags: erlang

Can you please explain what does this statement mean?

```
  NewList = [{{U, S, R}, I} || {{U, S, R}, I} <- Users, U =:= User],
```

where `USERS` is a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns all elements of `Users` which 1) match the pattern `{{U, S, R}, I}` (i.e. are 2-tuples where the first element is a 3-tuple); 2) `U` in that pattern is equal to the value of `User`.

See [the manual](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id83435) for details.

Comment: @user2384694: Just efficiency advice, use `NewList = [X || {{U, _, _}, _} = X <- Users, U =:= User],` which makes a lot less garbage on the heap and do less work.